# Website won't load PHP but does load HTML

Tags: php, html, web-services, nginx

I'm an amateur, working on a website which contains both .php and .html files.

Whilst I was testing my (simple) .php code by systematically uploading the edited .php files to the website and refreshing the browser, all of a sudden my browser (and any other browser for that matter) refuses to load ANY .php files on my site (even ones I didn't touch and that have always worked before). I keep getting a "504 Gateway Time-out (nginx)" error. HTML files are loaded without any problem.

I have no clue how to fix this.

EDIT: retrieved from my error log every time I have tried to access a .php file:

[*date*] [warn] [client 81.83.49.36] mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper

[*date*] [error] [client 81.83.49.36] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/*domainname*/error_docs/maintenance.html

EDIT2: the issue seems to have resolved itself, though I have no clue why. Is there a "shutdown and auto-reset after 4 hours" function when a .php script causes too many errors?

Comment: anything in the logs?

Comment: even simplest page doesn't work? f.e. with phpinfo()? you work on localhost or on some hosting provider?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  This came to me for review as it's your first post. Some relevant info you need to add to your question: Is your webserver running locally on your machine, on a machine in your organisation but not yours or remotely.  How are you uploading (via web interface, ftp or something else).  Can you still access the server to upload?  It may be that the question is more suitable for a different stack exchange site, but with that info added (edit your question), we can either help or point you to a site that can.

Comment: Ether your script is wrong and won't show anything to nginx in timeout site or your whole php engine died (php-fpm most likely in your case).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. The webserver runs remotely. I upload through ftp, and still can upload whatever I want (including .php files, though with said problem).

Comment: @Lambrusco yes, even phpinfo() fails.

Comment: @DmitryVerkhoturov "your whole php engine died" seems like the perfect description of what happened.

Comment: Did you contact your hosting company? What do they say?

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on your website locally? If you want to load php files locally you need to work with a server for example : http://www.wampserver.com/en/ , load your file to the www folder and start up the wamp server. Then you go in your browser to "localhost" and you will see your folders, click on a folder and it will load your site with html,php etc..

PHP is a server-side scripting language.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. The website is hosted on a remote web server.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occures when nginx working as frontend pushed the task to apache serving as backend, but didn't get answer back in time.

Actual causes may be too many requests, shortage of RAM available for the virtual server.

I think maybe resetting your virtual server may be a solution. Maybe something really went wrong with it.